# Keycloak may not support SAML 2.0 IdP initated SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, saml-2.0, idp

For context, here is my scenario, Keycloak is the Identity provider for a particular service, let's call it **Resurce1** where regular Keyclaok username and password login grants access to it.
Need to have a federative login for other Identity providers from the system. The first approach is the use the keyclaok as SP to be the authentication middleware for the **Resurce1** using SAML 2.0, already used across the board. Both are legacy systems.

> Important: Question is how to fix Saml SSO external IDP imitated SSO to work
> and not for a solution with OpenId Connect or other SSO protocols!!

**Testing setup**

- IdP Metadata imported into Keycloak realm SAML Identity Provider
- SP Keycloak Metadata imported into IdP
- Keycloak realm SP identity provider mappers that inject role (realm-management:realm-admin) to access client *security-admin-console*.

**Docker compose**

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local
services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
        - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
      environment:
        KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
        ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: BigB4!!s
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
      volumes:
        - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
        - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

**Scenario**
[image]

**Problems**

- I'm not a java developer
- Keyclaok SAML ACS handlers expect RelayState to be popualted
- Keyclaok RelayState has to be in this format=> ***RelayState: {session_code}.{tab_id}.{client_id}***, example => ***RelayState: DxcIxIfrTyrYVH-Z6VnY0FrC7I-C5yJcvqHWiN3ZS5k.pT8rTpU6OLA.security-admin-console***
- If relay state is not specified, error that client_id is null is shown inside logger
- If relay state is in this format ***..security-admin-console*** I get in UI **"Your login attempt timed out. Login will start from the beginning."** with a warning that code was not found.

Long story short, here is how keycloak is handling the SSO  https://github.com/kurzdigital/keycloak-1/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/IdentityBrokerService.java

**Need answers for**

- Is there any way that default behavior (more of an open id) implemented in keycloak can change?
- If not, beside the client-Id that can be hardcoded in relay state as : *RelayState: ..{client_id}* rest of expected values from Identity provider does not exist since sessions or cookies are keycloak (SP) generated values and not (IdP), how can we generate these or is there's now way not send it?
- Is the SAML external IdP imitated SSO functional, if so, in what version?

**Note**: SP (Keycloak) initiated SSO that goes to an external IdP **does work**, since it starts from Keycloak and RelayState has valid ***RelayState: {session_code}.{tab_id}.{client_id}*** format!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Keycloak, but **generally**, you can send the host and path the user is trying to get to (like a common landing page **inside** the protected realm) in the `RelayState` during an IdP-initiated transaction. Typically, the SP will consume that location and redirect the user to it with the application-specific token, whatever that may be.

Comment: Yep I know what RelayState is, @AndrewK., thing is that is not mandatory  send Relay State, being a IdP initiated SSO, let alone a particular PKCE OpenId concept in there not a SAML one.

Comment: While RelayState may be "optional" according to spec, most spec-compliant tools send the desired landing location to be redirected to after the SAML Assertion is consumed in the RelayState on an "Unsolicited Response" (which is what IdP-init sends). I'm not sure why you are applying PKCE/OIDC concepts here. One has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: That's literally what I said in previews comment, I don't wana send anything, keycloak expect to be there, and because I looked at the code I understood what relayState represents for them, even if is besides the point please send some references on where IdP initiated SSO has SP assertion consumption has the relay state required.  case I call this bullshit.

Comment: What I know is this RelayState is sent from SP to IdP with the expectance for the IdP to return the value back. And then the yes, relay state can be opaque in any format, case it was created from the SP and it is handled by service provider.

Comment: I didn't say that RelayState is REQUIRED at all times. In IdP-init, it's "optional" by spec and allows for the use of RelayState in any manner agreed upon by the federated parties. That being said, all of the commercial and open-source SP products that I know of that support IdP-initiated transactions expect "unsolicited responses" (which is what is generated by IdP-init since the SP didn't solicit it with an AuthnRequest) expert RelayState to contain the location the user should be sent to after consumption of the token. Call bullshit if you want, just trying to help. Good luck.

Comment: I know, thanks' man, sorry for being a d*ck.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, is just a behind the scene SP imitated sso that gives the impression of and IdP initiated login, still waiting for someone to get me a working solution for IdP initiated SSP.

Meantime a **HACK** that forces browser to do a redirect to Keycloak SSO SP imitated page, page that injects on the Authn request in relay state the proper **RelayState: {session_code}.{tab_id}.{client_id}** for the actual SSO response (Iframe instead of redirect works too keycloak CORS is problematic here, but there are ways).

**Vanilla js utilities for PKCE S256 Keycloak challenge:**

```
function dec2hex(dec) {
  var result = ("0" + dec.toString(16)).substr(-2);
  return result;
}

// Generate code verifier
function generateCodeVerifier() {
  var array = new Uint32Array(56 / 2);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
  var result = Array.from(array, dec2hex).join("");
  return result;
}


// Generate code challenge from code verifier
function sha256(plain) {
  // returns promise ArrayBuffer
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const data = encoder.encode(plain);
  var result = window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
  return result;
}

function base64urlencode(text) {
  var str = "";
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(text);
  var len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  var result = btoa(str)
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_")
    .replace(/=+$/, "");
    
  return result
}

async function generateCodeChallengeFromVerifier(code) {
  var hashed = await sha256(code);
  var base64encoded = base64urlencode(hashed);
  // todo: write a propper promise
  return base64encoded + "";
}
```

To disable PKCE S256, go on **keycloak specific client**, then on **Advanced Settings**  then search for **Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method**, and clean it up (don't recommend it, but there's no other way). When generating the SSO url if PKCE is disabled remove query params **code_challenge_method** and **code_challenge**.

> Here is where the hack happens, let's say at a client click with vanilla JS redirect to SP initiated SSO, that in the end get's the IdP identity and ACS assertions, **redirect_uri** can be used to target a particular page once SSO is completed.

```
let codeVerifier = generateCodeVerifier();
let codeChallenge = await generateCodeChallengeFromVerifier(codeVerifier) + "";

let realm = "xyz"
let host = "http://localhost:8080";
let clientId = "security-admin-console"
let redirect = host + "/auth/admin/" + realm + "/console/" 
let encodedRedirect = encodeURIComponent(redirect);
let kc_idp_hint = 'idp_id';
let spInitiatedSSOUrl = host + "/auth/realms/" + realm + "/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=" + clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + encodedRedirect +"&kc_idp_hint=" + kc_idp_hint + "&scope=openid&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=" + codeChallenge;

window.location = spInitiatedSSOUrl;
```

The only truly working solution (but is not IdP initiated) for when is to call directly the SP www.sp/handler, inside the handler using keycloak-js do:

```
const idpHint = 'whatever';
const keycloak = new Keycloak();

keycloak.responseType = 'code';
keycloak.init({
  scope: 'openid',
  flow: 'standard',
  pkceMethod: 'S256', // remove if PKCE flow is not needed
  checkLoginIframe: false,
}).then(authenticated => {
console.log(authenticated);
if(authenticated){
  console.log("logged in");
}
else{
  keycloak.login({idpHint: idpHint});
}
```